# Creating UI using Flixel

Tags: screen, ui-design, flixel

I am new to game development but familiar with programming languages. I have started using Flixel and have a working Breakout game with score and lives.

What I am trying to do is add a **Start Screen** before actually loading the game.

I have a create function that adds all the game elements to the stage:

```
override public function create():void
   // all game elements
{
```

How can I add this pre-load **Start Screen**? I'm not sure if I have to add in the code to this create function or somewhere else and what code to actually add.

Eventually I would also like to add saving, loading, options and upgrades too. So any advice with that would be great.

Here is my main **game.as**:

```
package
{
    import org.flixel.*;

    public class Game extends FlxGame
    {
        private const resolution:FlxPoint = new FlxPoint(640, 480);
        private const zoom:uint = 2;
        private const fps:uint = 60;

        public function Game()
        {
            super(resolution.x / zoom, resolution.y / zoom, PlayState, zoom);
            FlxG.flashFramerate = fps;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, while there might be several ways to do it, I've found it easiest to make a seperate State for each of my game 'sections' - so, the Main Menu, the Game Itself, and the Game Over/Scoreboard screens would each be their own state: `MenuState`, `PlayState`, and `EndState`, respectively.

So, make a new Class: `MenuState.as` and make sure it extends `FlxState`. In the `create()` method of `MenuState`, create and add all of your UI objects.

In your `game.as`, change this line:

```
super(resolution.x / zoom, resolution.y / zoom, PlayState, zoom);
```

Change it to:

```
super(resolution.x / zoom, resolution.y / zoom, MenuState, zoom);
```

In `MenuState`, somewhere (probably in a Button or KeyUp logic), you can use `FlxG.switchState(new PlayState);` to exit your Menu and start your game.

I recommend you have your game's logic in it's own state if possible, because it makes it easier to load, reset, and exit the game itself on demand.

Comment: ...I KNEW this question seemed familiar!
I answered it over on Stack Overflow!
I think it (and the answer) should be over here, though... makes more sense to keep it in GameDev.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a screen **before** all assets are loaded you have to use a preloader.
You can read about this [here](http://www.flashgamedojo.com/wiki/index.php?title=Preloader_%28Flixel%29). Flixel provides simple preloader (FlxPreloader) that is easy to understand and to customize.

Answer (score -2):

in the main.hx chang first State on MenuState (Its how Scenes in Unity man)

Comment: Could you clarify? This is somewhat hard to follow.